# Char is an arithmetic type?

Tags: c++, matrix, char, arithmetic-expressions

I created a Matrix class, using

```
static_assert(std::is_arithmetic<T>::value,"");
```

to check if the template type is an arithmetic type. So I tried with

```
Matrix<char> matrix1(3,3); // ctor takes number of rows and columns
```

and it works. The static_assert function is not called with char type. It is normal? char is seen like an arithmetic type?

Comment: Yes, it is, but you should probably use `signed char` or `unsigned char` instead. *Unlike* `short`, `int`, etc., `signed char` is a distinct type from `char`, so you probably don't want to do arithmetic with it (you don't know if it's signed in general).

Comment: If you're a perfectly moral being, you should only consider `signed char` and `unsigned char` as arithmetic types, and reserve `char` purely as a system-interfacing I/O type.

Comment: @Mehrdad Thank you. I will never use char for arithmetic operations! ;). In fact I thought char was _italic_not_italic_ an arithmetic type...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_arithmetic):

> If T is an arithmetic type (that is, an integral type or a floating-point type), provides the member constant value equal true. For any other type, value is false.

`char` is an integral type, so the answer is `true`. The fact that the small integers that fit in a `char` are often *interpreted* as codepoints in a particular character encoding space is secondary.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's just as a normal integer as any other (int, long, short). That's also a common practice in C(++) to use it for arithmetic, e. g. for converting a digit to its corresponding printable character, you can write

```
char printable = digit + '0';
```